# Trouble getting https to work with self signed certificate on aws elastic load balancer

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-web-services, self-signed, amazon-elb

I am having issue configuring https on my aws elastic load balancer using a self-signed certificate. After I've done with the set up, making connection to https endpoint does not work. http connection is still fine.

Here's what I did.

1. Generate the self-signed certificate using this command

   *openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt*
2. Verified the key and certificate is working by using this command:

   *openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -check*
   *openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout*
3. Convert the certificate the key and the cert into a .pem encoded format to comply with aws certificate requirement.

   *openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -text > private.pem*

   *openssl x509 -inform PEM -in certificate.crt > public.pem*
4. Upload the certificate to my elastic load balancer using the the AWS Management Console
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_UpdatingLoadBalancerSSL.html. For the private key and public cert value, I used the private.pem and public.pem that were generated in step 3.
5. Go into EBL Listener configuration, added a https listener and used the certificate that I just uploaded. Here's the configuration for the Listener:

   [image]

Any thought on what might be wrong in my configuration? Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you get when you make requests to https?  Timeout?

Comment: yes, the request timeout.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue... Do you have any other info for me?

Comment: Using https, the curl command gets stuck at the "connect()" step and then time out. Here's something interesting. If I upload the self-signed certificate using the AWS UI tool, I was able to upload the cert. However, when using AWS CLI upload-server-certificate command, I get this error 

"A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred: Invalid Public Key Certificate."

This tells me there might be something wrong with the certificate/private key. 

Did you generate a self-signed cert for your aws balancer? What steps did you use to generate it? Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Does the Security Groups of the Load Balancer include an inbound HTTPS 443 Port for source 0.0.0.0/0?  I just spent a few hours until I finally found this solution.

Comment: After 2 hours on support with everybody, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the default security group created for ELBs (when no security group is specified) only allows incoming connections on port 80.